# Resizing a bone in OnPreRender does not resize for current Camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a custom avatar system for my Unity3D game, giving players the ability to upload their own avatars.
As my game is for VR, I of course want to show the body to the user, hiding the head in the process.
I was thinking to scale the head bone down to zero for only the VR camera, so that mirrors and other cameras still see the head.

I already tried all kinds of different methods, including Update, LateUpdate, OnPreCull. Some of them scale the head actually down, but then for every camera in the scene, not just for the one I want.

```cs
private void OnPreRender()
{
    Original = head.localScale;
    head.localScale = Vector3.zero;
}

private void OnPostRender()
{
    head.localScale = Original;
}
```

I expect the head to scale to 0 (nothing), but the only thing that happens is that the child objects of the bone move to the downscaled position, but actually don't scale.

Edit: After further testing, I noticed that gameObject.SetActive works as expected. The whole avatar becomes invisible for just that camera with the script attached. The scaling doesn't seem to work. My guess is that the scaling might need more frames to process. And when the render function is executed, it is only half way through scaling.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the efficient way do do it. You'd be much better off placing hands on a different layer, and switch off culliing for that layer on a VR camera. This way you won't need to touch transforms, and that's one less native->managed call for unity (layers are handled on the native side)

Comment: That is sadly not possible. As users can create and upload their own custom avatars, I need to have a way to enable every user to easily upload their avatars. Having them to detach their head from the body and putting it on a different layer will just cause confusion.

Comment: placing an object on a layer requires no detatching. layer culling is done per-camera

Comment: What I mean is that the user would have to have the head and body be different parts. Individual meshes. Though I want to give my users the ability to have a single mesh for their avatar.

Comment: I think its not a great idea to have the same mesh for hands and head that are visible from user point of view - head wont be automatically culled and will require pre-face culling even for a user whose head it is.edit: I missed the part about user uploading their meshes -I get what your problem is now

Answer (score 0):

By default, Unity appears to cache the matrices of a skinned mesh on a per frame basis.

It is possible to force a skinned mesh to recalculate the matrix on each render by setting this property on each character mesh.

```
SkinnedMeshRenderer.forceMatrixRecalculationPerRender = true;
```

[Unity Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer-forceMatrixRecalculationPerRender.html)

Setting this property to true on all of your character meshes will enable you to control bone scale on just a specific camera.